# How to update other widget after future builder get data

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to update the header widget after the future builder bellow it gets data from DB.

Consider this simplified code

```
Column (
 children: [
  Text('Data is loading'), // I want to changed it into `Data is loaded`
  FutureBuilder(
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
     return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
     );
    }
    if (!isCacheInitialized) {
     _loadDB(); // get data from db
     isCacheInitialized = true;
    }
    return ListView.builder
   },
   future: storage.ready,
  )
 ]
)
```

What I already tried but failed

- Call `setState` after `_loadDB`

result in error

> setState() called during build.

So how to change the text `Data is loading` into `Data is loaded` after `FutureBuilder` gets the data?

Answer (score 0):

Call setState inside the _loadDB() function instead. So, before the _loadDB() function hands over to Widget Build, It would have set the data you want.

Comment: `setState` shouldn't be called inside FutureBuilder as I try it, because it will cause infinite loop of builder hence the error. I'm not yet find the solution for this problem